How to web-scrape a dynamic table within a website?
I am attaching the website link here: https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/azerbaijan/misli-premier-league/709#id:64075
I have drafted multiple version of the code and already lost track of everything so I will just paste my code here instead:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Make sure ChromeDriver is available in your environment


url = "https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/azerbaijan/misli-premier-league/709#id:64075"

try:
    # Open the page in the browser
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the table to be fully loaded (wait for the table class to appear)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[contains(@class, 'sc-c347313f-8.kLmLmP')]")))

    # Scrape the rows of the table
    rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//tr")

    table_data = []
    
    for row in rows:
        # Get the cells in each row, checking both td and th
        cells = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//td")
        if not cells:  # For header rows, use th
            cells = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//th")
        
        row_data = [cell.text.strip() for cell in cells if cell.text.strip() != '']
        if row_data:
            table_data.append(row_data)

    # Convert the scraped data into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)

    # Print the DataFrame
    print("Extracted Table Data:")
    print(df)

    
    df.to_csv("scraped_table.csv", index=False)

finally:
    # Close the browser once done
    driver.quit()


I tried doing basically everything possible. I made sure that the issue is not linked to anything external like webdriver. I am so lost at this point. I tried like 50 different version and still no results. All I need is to scrape the table below called 'Player Statistics'.

The problem you are facing is that the table element doesn't exist until you scroll down to a certain element.
It dynamically loads when you scroll to the parent element.
To fix the problem you have to first scroll down to the parent div element and then wait for the table to be available in the DOM.
Also, the XPath for the table was wrong. Searching for a table element returns only one table, so I've used that to find the data.
try the following code.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/azerbaijan/misli-premier-league/709#id:64075"

try:
    # Open the page in the browser
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the table to be fully loaded (wait for the table class to appear)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    # First get the parent element that loads on the page load without scrolling
    parent = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-testid='league_info']")))
    #scroll down to get the parent into view.
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", parent)
    #then you'll find that the table is present.
    table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table")))

    # Scrape the rows of the table
    rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//tr")

    table_data = []

    for row in rows:
        # Get the cells in each row, checking both td and th
        cells = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//td")
        if not cells:  # For header rows, use th
            cells = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//th")

        row_data = [cell.text.strip() for cell in cells if cell.text.strip() != '']
        if row_data:
            table_data.append(row_data)

    # Convert the scraped data into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)

    # Print the DataFrame
    print("Extracted Table Data:")
    print(df)


    df.to_csv("scraped_table.csv", index=False)

finally:
    # Close the browser once done
    driver.quit()


thank you sooo muchhh.
I still have one question though. Since I am pretty new to web scraping, how do I choose what filters I want to apply to the dynamic table? Also what would you recommend to avoid legal issues?
Thanks in advance!

You need to understand how the DOM is updating and how to select the element properly. You have to find the aspects for filters and when the DOM changes, you have to wait for appropriate changes.
It would be faster to use the request library, apply the filters for yourself with the request, get the data, and scrape it with beautifulsoup.
And for the legal aspect, I don't know if there is any legal issue with scraping public site data. But you can check if there is any user agreement or anything in the site. Or your local government has any law against it.
